# WCF service keeps returning false

Tags: c#, sql, database, wcf, ado.net

So I created and invoked a WCF service in C#, but keep getting a false back, I am unsure as to why it is. It might be to do with the connection string but changing it from the current just gives me errors.

Here's my code:

```
 //Create the new connection
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

 //Create the query
 String myQuery = "INSERT INTO Player  (registrationID,  firstName,  lastName,  phoneNumber,  Address,  dateOfBirth) " +
                   " VALUES ('" + registrationID + "', '" + firstName + "', '" + lastName + "', '" + phoneNumber + "', '" + Address + "', '" + dateOfBirth + "');";

  //The connectionString can be found in the properties table of the database
  myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ADO_LINQ/ADO_LINQ/App_Data/MyDatabase.sdf";

  //Initialuze the command
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
  SqlDataReader myReader;

  //Run the command
  try 
  {
          myConnection.Open();
          myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
          //Return true if it was successful
          return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex) 
   {
          return false;
   }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `catch` block so the service can crash and tell you what's wrong?

Comment: What are the errors? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And there is no point to use `ExecuteReader` since you are using `INSERT` statement. Because your query doesn't return any data, it just insert data. Just use `ExecuteNonQuery` instead. Also use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and objects.

Comment: There's little point in catching an exception if you don't do anything with it (i.e., log it or something else).  Simply returning false when you encounter an exception means you're swallowing that exception, which will make troubleshooting it a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Soner pointed out, your code is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks, and this can be remedied by using parameterized queries.  Also, best practice is to use a `using` block with the connection so it is properly closed and disposed of once the code in the `using` block is exited (currently you're not even closing the connection when you're done).

Also, `ExecuteNonQuery` is sufficient for this - it will run the command and then return the number of rows affected (which should be 1 in this case).  You can check the number of rows affected and use that to determine success/failure, in addition to using a `catch` block in the case of an exception.  Realistically I would not expect anything other than the value of 1 *unless* an exception was thrown while executing the command.

Finally your posted code is swallowing the exception.  You should do something with the exception (log it, execute some other code, rethrow it - depending on the requirements of your app) rather than simply returning false.

Putting it all together:

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection())
{

    // Create the query
    String myQuery = "INSERT INTO Player  (registrationID,  firstName,  lastName,  phoneNumber,  Address,  dateOfBirth) " +
               " VALUES (@RegistrationID, @FirstName, @LastName, @PhoneNumber, @Address, @DateOfBirth)";

    //The connectionString can be found in the properties table of the database
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:/Users/User/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/ADO_LINQ/ADO_LINQ/App_Data/MyDatabase.sdf";

    //Initialuze the command
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // Here you add the values for the parameters in the query
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@RegistrationID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = registrationID;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstName;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastName;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@PhoneNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = phoneNumber;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = address;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateOfBirth", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateOfBirth;

    //Run the command
    try 
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        int rowsAffected = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rowsAffected == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

     }
     catch (Exception ex) 
     {
         // Do something with the exception, like logging it so you can review the error 
         return false;
     }
 }
```

The above code wraps the call in a `using` statement.  When the command is created, the parameters are added to the `SqlCommand.Parameters` collection, and then `ExecuteNonQuery` is returned.  If the result is 1, true is returned, otherwise false is returned.  If an error is encountered, false is returned but again you should do something with the exception so you can troubleshoot if needed.

Comment: Thank you, this was really allot of help! You gave way more than asked for and hope other people will find this useful! thnx again.

Comment: Just one more thing, I seem to be having trouble with the connection string, I took the one from the propperties but doesn't seem to work. ny suggestions?

Comment: @Cornelis - What kind of trouble?  Do you get an exception? What database are you using (MS SQL, Access, MySQL, etc)?  You can check http://www.connectionstrings.com/ as well - they have connection strings for just about everything.

Comment: SQL, but using the build in one with visual studio. Getting a exception.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Ok so in full detail I get the error at .Open() and is a SQLexception:

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: @Cornelis - I'm not sure what the connection string should be, but you might want to try back slashes instead of forward slashes - `@"Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ADO_LINQ\ADO_LINQ\App_Data\MyDatabase.sdf"` (the `@` marks the string as a literal and removes the need to escape the `\`).